# WMI object available through commandlet but not through Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

why can I get a WMI object using `Get-CMBoundaryGroup`, but not directly using `Get-WmiObject`? I get `Invalid namespace "root\sms\site_CAS"` when using `Get-WmiObject`

```
$boundaryGroup1 = Get-CMBoundaryGroup -Name 'BoundaryGroupName'
$class = $boundaryGroup1.ManagedObject.__CLASS #SMS_BoundaryGroup
$namespace = $boundaryGroup1.ManagedObject.__NAMESPACE #root\sms\site_CAS

$boundaryGroup2 = Get-WmiObject -Class $class -Namespace $namespace #Invalid namespace "root\sms\site_CAS"
```

Comment: "invalid namespace". The namespace doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working properly in my test lab.

Based on your error code, I recommend you use the WMI Explorer to review your namespace. https://wmie.codeplex.com/

[image]

Comment: The namespace is not available for me. Apparently I need to run it on my primary site server.